# Remote Connection to QuickBooks Data using RSSBus

Tags: c#, ado.net, quickbooks

I'm using the RSSbus ADO.net library to access a QuickBooks file for import and exporting from an application I'm working on. I have had success connecting and getting data using the local file connection setting, but I cannot seem to get the URL connection setting to work. Reading the documentation has not been helpful. Has anyone else used the library to connection from a Web Application to a user's local QuickBooks file?

Currently from what I have understood from the documentation I should just be able have a connection string set to: URL=http://localhost:2080 and it'll connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickBooks by itself does not natively have a method for you to connect 3rd party applications over a network. However, this is possible if you have a local application that can facilitate communication between the 3rd party app and QuickBooks over a network.

The QuickBooks ADO.NET Provider by RSSBus comes with a QBConnector application. This is installed to [C:\Program Files (x86)\RSSBus\RSSBus QuickBooks Data Provider\QBConnector] by default. The QBConnector can be copied to the machine running QuickBooks and run from the command-line to facilitate communication between QuickBooks and the QuickBooks Data Provider. The URL/User/Password properties are all used to point to and login to the QBConnector.

The QBConnector is explained in greater detail in the online help here:
http://rssbus.com/kb/help/RQR1-A/pg_qbconnector.rst