# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider - Error using QuickBooks

Tags: c#, entity-framework, quickbooks

I'm using QuickBooks connector in class library. And accessing class library from console app. I'm getting this error when try to add new DbSet item to context:

```
The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.RSSBus.QuickBooks' 
is either not registered in the machine or application config file, 
or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
```

How I can solve it? Shall I register this provide in app.config file somehow?

Comment: Can you post your config file? And your inner exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.RSSBus.QuickBooks' 
>   is either not registered in the machine

I guess so far you just got the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QuickBooks.Net/).
In several cases, when working with ADO.NET providers [you have to install them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126405/remote-connection-to-quickbooks-data-using-rssbus) on your machine via a regular setup file (.MSI or whatever).
I think the one you are looking for can be downloaded from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.QuickBooksADONETProvider).

[Here](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/quickbooks/) you will find a commercial one, in theory optimized for Entity Framework.